# How can I prove that this series is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to check convergence of series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=3}a_n, $ where $a_n = \frac{n! - 2n}{n^n}.$ I've already tried ratio and squareroot tests, but limits of $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ turned out to both equal to $1$. I also tried Weierstrass criterion by writing down that $a_n < b_n = \frac{n!}{n^n}$ and trying to show that $b_n$ converges (and so $a_n$ would converge) - couldn't do that. Can anyone help? I don't have idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Take logarithms for $b_n$ and use Stirling approximation

Comment: You can use the ratio test for this one. Use your $b_n$ terms, and apply the ratio test, and you should get something like $1/e < 1$.

Comment: @JimmyJummy thanks, I've actually tried ratio test (in my country it's called d'Alembert criterion), but for some reason I thought that $lim_{n -> \infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^n$ is $1$... now I see why it is 1/e.

Can you switch from comment to answer so that I can mark the question as answered?

Comment: I suggest an edit "... I've already tried d'Alembert criteria, also called Ratio test, and Cauchy... "  I would guess most American Calculus II students would recognize Ratio test but be unfamiliar with the name, d'Alembert criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the ratio test you obtain something like
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n \frac{n!-2}{n!-2n}.
$$

It is not hard to prove that the value of this limit is indeed $e^{-1}<1$. So the series converges absolutely and therefore converges.